# Postgres access a single column by two different programs

Tags: sql, postgresql

My question is probably very specific to Postgres, probably not.

A program which I cannot modify has access to Postgress via npgsql and a simple select command, all I know.

I also have access via npgsql. The table is defined as:

```
-- Table: public.n_data

-- DROP TABLE public.n_data;

CREATE TABLE public.n_data
(
  u_id integer,
  p_id integer NOT NULL,
  data text,
  CONSTRAINT nc PRIMARY KEY (p_id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
ALTER TABLE public.n_data
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

(If that info is useful anyway)
I access one single big column, read from it and write back to it.

This all works fine so far.

The Question is: how does Postgres handles it if we write at the same time.
Any Problems there?

And if Postgres does not handle that automatically, how about when I read the data, process it and in the meantime data changes, and I write back that data after I processed it---> lost data.

Its a bit tricky to test for data integrity, since this datablock is huge, and corruptions are hard to find.

I do it with c# if that means anything.

Comment: Read about [rows locking](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/explicit-locking.html)

Comment: Read about rational database locking machanizems. As far as I know Postgresql uses  MVCC https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Locking (in most<sup>1</sup>) relational databases (including Postgres) is always on *row* level, never on column level (it's columns and rows in a relational database not "cells", "fields" or "records")

If two transactions modify the same row, the second one will have to wait until the first one commits or rolls back.

If two transactions modify different rows then they can do that without any problems as long as they don't modify columns that are part of a unique constraint or primary key to the same value.

Read access to data is never blocked in Postgres by regular DML statements. So yes while one transaction modifies data, another one will see the old data until the first transaction commits the changes ("read consistency").

To handle lost updates you can either use the serializable isolation level or make all transactions follow the pattern that they *first* need to obtain a lock on the row (`select ... for update`) and hold that until they are finished. Search for "pessimistic locking" to get more details about this pattern.

Another option is to include a "modified" timestamp in your table. When a process reads the data it also reads the modification timestamp. When it sends back the new changes it includes a `where modified_at = <value obtained when reading>` - if the data has changed the condition will not hold true and nothing will be updated and you need to restart your transaction. Search for "optimistic locking" to find more details about this pattern.

---

<sup>1 some DBMS do page locking and some escalate many row level locks to a table lock. Neither is the case in Postgres</sup>